# javascript how to run a function again after it ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that updates a table on my html page through ajax. This ajax call takes an extremely long time to finish. I was lead to believe that the following code would run it again once the ajax call had finished with no memory leak, as the function would end before delay in setTimeout did. However, when I look at the processes with chrome's developer tool, I can see many instances of my function makeTable() going and I get the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` in the console. Is there a better way to do this?

```
 function makeTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "TableView.asp",
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function (ret) {
        $("#info_display").html(ret);
    });
    setTimeout(makeTable, 5000);
 }
```

Comment: `Internal Server Error` has nothing to do with the Javascript (except if you send bad value through AJAX).

Comment: Why not just make the call inside `done()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
setTimeout(makeYellowTable, 5000);
```

Should be within callback function "done"

```
.done(function (ret) {
    $("#info_display").html(ret);
    setTimeout(makeYellowTable, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply move `makeYellowTable()` function call inside a ajax callback

```
 function makeTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "TableView.asp",
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function (ret) {
        $("#info_display").html(ret);
        makeYellowTable(); //<--- here this function is called only after the ajax completes.
    });

}
```

`makeYellowTable()` will only be called after ajax call completes. And it will be called once.

Comment: wouldn't this lead to a memory leak, since the first function never technically ends?

Comment: I noticed the function `makeYellowTable()` that OP is trying to call inside a `setTimeout()` is not the same function `makeTable()`. :):)

Answer (score 1):

Use `success` for preventing errors and call `makeYellowTable` there when it's finished.

```
function makeTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "TableView.asp",
        type: "GET",
        success: function() {
            $("#info_display").html(ret);
            makeYellowTable();

            // or with a timeout again
            // setTimeout(makeYellowTable, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems here.  First, the purpose of the .done() method chained on the end of the $.ajax() call is to call some code when the response comes back from the server.  Whatever logic you need to do need to be done in there, not by using setTimeout.  Second, your php script is not working correctly.  Without seeing that code I don't know what's going on but it looks like there is an error there which is causing your server to return 500.

Comment: There is no php script.

Comment: sorry, your .asp, not php.  The service that you are calling with $.ajax is returning a 500 error.

Comment: ok. Do you have any idea why it would run correctly the first time, but throw errors on all other calls then? This behavior was what lead me to believe that the way I was calling it again was incorrect.

Comment: Without seeing the code I have no way of knowing what is causing an error.  Can you step through the code in a debugger?  That will give you a better idea.